# What are the MongoDB limitations when installed using "linux package file"?

Tags: linux, mongodb

There is what the the actual page says [image: mongoDB linux package].

Apart from this information

- Keep in mind that this legacy Linux 64 build may lack the performance optimizations present in targeted builds.
- This distribution does not include the SSL encryption

There is no much documentation available on mongoDB site as well.

What are the exact performance limitations if linux package is used instead of the Redhat one on the Redhat 7 machine ?

Verified that binaries provided have different md5sums so they are different :)